# Windows 8 x64 sound settings keep resetting automatically

Tags: windows-8, system-sounds

I like using the OS with no system sounds, no asterisks, error bleeps, etc. I like to keep "no sounds" as my sound scheme but every so often it happens that the system will start making sounds and the sound settings will be set to "windows default". This happens during use, not after restart and very intermittently, say once a week but it has actually been happening for a long time and it is annoying. What can be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

When you are on the Personalization screen and change the desktop background the sound scheme reverts to Windows Default.

This could be a cause of the sound changing.

Comment: That seems to be what was causing the issue for me. That is a  really annoying behaviour!

Comment: Are there any other way that it could happen? My sound scheme reverts at irregular intervals, on all three Windows 8 computers that I have. I haven't changed the desktop background in years.